# I am not able to alter Spring cloud gate way response in Global filter based on response headers from down stream?

Tags: java, spring-cloud

My Goal is to receive some token from downstream server response headers by using  ServerHttpResponseDecorator without this I am not able to get response headers in GlobalFilter.  based on token I am planning to alter downstream response by raising a custom exception and handled in ErrorWebExceptionHandler.

The problem is once I have read the response headers from downstream service even exception also not able to stop the flow I am getting an original response whatever is coming from downstream service but if I raised an exception before headers reading It is working as expected.

GlobalFilter Sample code

```
   @Component
   public class CustomFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -2;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();

        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {

            @Override
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {

                String tokenFromHeader = super.getHeaders().getFirst("TOKEN");
                String regIdFromHeader = super.getHeaders().getFirst("regId");
                if (false) { // if (true) { It is hadled by exception handler as expected

                    // I have some Buginese logic here
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }

                if (tokenFromHeader != null && regIdFromHeader != null) {
                    if (true) {
                        //I have some Buginese logic here

                        // No use I am getting original response from down streams
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }

                }

                return getDelegate().getHeaders();
            }
        };

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build()); 
    }

}
```

Exception Handler

```
    public class MyWebExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {



            byte[] bytes = ( "Some custom text").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

            return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
        }
    }
```

Expected out put is

Some custom text

But I am getting an original response

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/rewrite/ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.java for an example on how to modify the response body.

Comment: You're actually trying to modify the response before it has been received

Comment: if (tokenFromHeader != null && regIdFromHeader != null)  for this purpose I have added this condition @spencergibb

Comment: I tried a different approach for modifying response body but not working as expected posted the same in spring forums https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/942  I will try your example @spencergibb